# Extent Report 4 not creating report

Tags: java, extentreports, selenium-extent-report, extent

I am trying to create extent report version v4.0.9 but unable to do so.
Below code I have written to setUp class which has all before method and aftermethos and the same class is extented to Utilities class where I am performing tests.

Here is code for setUp class

```
public class AIG_SetUp {
    protected static ExtentLoggerReporter logger;
    protected static ExtentReports extent;
    protected static ExtentTest log;

     @BeforeTest(alwaysRun = true)
     public void starttest() {
            logger = new ExtentLoggerReporter(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
            extent = new ExtentReports();
            extent.attachReporter(logger);
            System.err.close(); // written to remove JAVA 9 incompatibility.. continued below
            System.setErr(System.out); // continue.. and remove the warnings
            extent.setSystemInfo("User Name" , "Sobhit");
     }

     @AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
     public void endReport(ITestResult result) {
          try {
               if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
                    log.log(Status.FAIL , "Test cases Failed" + result.getName());
                    log.log(Status.FAIL , "Test cases Failed" + result.getThrowable());
               } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP) {
                    log.log(Status.SKIP , "Test case skipped is" + result.getName());
               }
          } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
          }
     }

     @AfterTest(alwaysRun = true)
     public void endReport() {
          extent.flush();

          }
     }
```

And here is the utilities class which is extented to above class.

```
public class UtilitiesOps extends AIG_SetUp {

     @Test(groups = {"Core-Smoke"}, description = "List all media types")
     public void Verify_List_all_media_types() {
         extent.attachReporter(logger);
         extent = new ExtentReports();
         log = extent.createTest("List all media types");
         log.assignCategory("Utilities Operations");

     }
```

Couple of important points to mention
Now I am not getting error, before I was getting null pointer exception but now no error. 
Also Code runs fine but not generating the extent report. 
If I put everything in one class with no before test and stuff, able to create the report. Not sure why is going wrong.

I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer for this after reading about it.

basically I was doing the beforetest without static variables where as it has to be statically intiated because of other global variables.

The below code fixed my issues.

```
@BeforeTest(alwaysRun = true)
     public static void starttest() {
            logger = new ExtentLoggerReporter(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
            extent = new ExtentReports();
            extent.attachReporter(logger);
            System.err.close(); // written to remove JAVA 9 incompatibility.. continued below
            System.setErr(System.out); // continue.. and remove the warnings
            extent.setSystemInfo("User Name" , "Sobhit");
     }
```